# Display latest record of a table (all columns) in a label or a textbox on Access form

Tags: ms-access

I want to display the latest row (latest record based on date) in a table called "Lifespan_settings" . In that table I have only two fields : Date_Edit, Lifespan

I want to display the latest value from Lifespan field on label123 on form123.

I believe I have to query first to get the latest record then *only later I can change the label control source to query* . However, I could not find any example to query the latest data. 
I made a query like below, but it display ALL data from my table.

```
SELECT Max(Lifespan_settings.Date_Edit) AS MaxOfDate_Edit, Lifespan_settings.Lifespan
FROM Lifespan_settings
GROUP BY Lifespan_settings.Lifespan;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Date_Edit, Lifespan
FROM Lifespan_settings
ORDER BY Date_Edit DESC;
```

Also, you can do this using functions in textbox control source:

```
=DLookup("Lifespan","Lifespan_settings","Date_Edit=#" & Format(DMax("Date_Edit","Lifespan_settings"),"mm\/dd\/yyyy hh:nn:ss") & "#")
```

Comment: Thank u! Anyway, do u know how can I display that value from the query, in a textbox? do i need to write anything in the control source?

Comment: I  updated the answer, but the values calculated fields appear with delay, so I prefer to push the values to textbox rather than calculating in control source.